# Linking requirements with function tests

Tags: testing, agile, functional-testing, requirements

I'm building a command line tool where I can execute commands like this on the input:

```
PROMPT>userName=Seán<CR>
PROMPT>zodiacSign=Virgo<CR>
```

where userName is a string type and zodiacSign is of type enumerator.

I also have auto-complete such that I can hit the tab key and get clues, like this

```
PROMPT>zodiacSign=C<TAB>
         Cancer
         Capricorn
PROMPT>zodiacSign=Ca
```

The thing is that I'm getting more and more subtle requirements which I'm finding more and more difficult to document into User Stories. For example, I just received the requirement where if I hit carriage-return for the following:

```
PROMPT>zodiacSign=Can<CARRIAGE-RETURN>
```

The software should then auto-complete the command **zodiacSign=Cancer** and execute it since it is the only option.

I will put in place function tests to test each of these nuances. By doing this, I can demo User Stories via my Function Tests.

But what convenient tool would you recommend where I can store requirements / user stories, perhaps even linking them to function tests? Perhaps this tool includes coverage graphs.

Answer (score 3):

Who is the audience for the requirements? If it is a developer, I'd say that the version control system is a great place to store them. :-)

I would recommend the use of Cucumber or FitNesse. Using the tests as requirements is the way to go.

Cucumber example:

```
Scenario:
   If a single match is available and the carriage return is pressed
   auto-complete should accept the match

Given valid Zodiac Signs are "Cancer,Capricorn"
When the user enters "zodiacSign=Can<CARRIAGE-RETURN>" at the prompt
Then the shell should auto-complete to "zodiacSign=Cancer"
```

This is a completely executable test and does well to describe the required functionality.

Hope that helps!

Brandon

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [FitNesse](http://fitnesse.org/).  It's a combination of a requirements Wiki and functional test execution framework.

When you write the requirements, you put them in a table where you have sample data and expected results.  Click "test" and FitNesse parses the table, and makes the call.  Pretty cool.

Answer (score 2):

FitNesse is indeed a popular tool, but some would argue that [FitNesse is evil](http://it-essence.xs4all.nl/roller/technology/entry/the_fatal_flaws_of_fitnesse) (it can be misused easily, and suffers from [numerous issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401390/fitnesse-vs-anyother-subsystem-testing-tool)). A good open-source cross-platform alternative would be [**soapUI**](http://www.soapui.org/About-SoapUI/what-is-soapui.html).

**soapUI** can manage [functional testing](http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/functional-testing.html), as well as [keep track of your system's requirements](http://www.soapui.org/Working-with-Projects/managing-requirements.html), use cases and user stories, and link them to the tests.

It has a nice GUI with what-not (including [coverage graphs](http://www.soapui.org/Coverage/introduction.html), like you want!). Most of the features are included in the free version.

Answer (score 2):

For your need, take a look at [QMetry](http://www.qmetry.com/).
It's a very complete tool that allow you to define requirements, test cases, test scenarios and also the launching of test scenarios.
Reporting is also nice and HMI is very user friendly.

Hope this help